# Не по формату [Метка для модераторов]

Tags: дефект, статус-завершено, локализация, метки, мета

На [странице меток](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/tags?tab=new):

> [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

На том же SOen всё ок:

> [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Строка в традусёре: https://ru.traducir.win/string/4231

Добавил вариант:

> метка-для-модераторов

Comment: Подправил число для обязательной метки. А с красной подождём, что NC ответит. Хотя мог бы и от себя применить, но стоит разобраться в проблеме.